# Scipy pearsonr returns tuple instead of PearsonRResult object

Tags: python, scipy, confidence-interval, scipy.stats

I'm trying to use scipy to get the confidence interval for a Pearson R correlation. Scipy documentation states that `scipy.stats.pearsonr` returns an object with a method `confidence_interval()`.

When I run their example code I get a tuple as the result and so cannot calculate the confidence interval.

I'm using scipy version 1.7.3 and python 3.7.0 on Windows 10

What am I doing wrong?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
x, y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [10, 9, 2.5, 6, 4, 3, 2]
res = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
res
```

Should give:
`PearsonRResult(statistic=-0.828503883588428, pvalue=0.021280260007523286)`
But I get:

```
(-0.8285038835884277, 0.021280260007523345)
```

And when I try:

```
res.confidence_interval(confidence_level=0.9)
```

as per the scipy docs example, I of course get an error `"AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'confidence_interval'"`

Answer (score 1):

In Scipy version 1.7, `pearsonr` returns a tuple rather than an object. Here's the documentation for your version:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.7.1/reference/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html

It looks like returning an object as you are expecting was introduced in [version 1.9](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.9.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html).

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I thought I had the most up to date version of scipy but it was only the most recent one compatible with python 3.7 detected by pip. Upgraded to python 3.10 and scipy 1.11 and it works fine.